# Const dynamic_pointer_cast when is needed

Tags: c++, c++17

It's not clear for me when is needed to use dynamic_pointer_cast or dynamic_cast with const. Please someone explain it to me. I made a const object of type A but as far as I've seen there's no need to use dynamic_pointer_cast with const at downcast, so when would be needed a const downcast ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


struct A {
    int x = 10;
    virtual ~A() = default;
};

struct B :public A {
  int y = 11;  
};


int main()
{
   const std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<B>();
   auto b = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(a); //why shouldn't be dynamic_pointer_cast<const B>(a);
   b->y;

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constness of a pointer is unrelated to constness of what it points to.

If `a` was a pointer to `const A`:

```
      std::shared_ptr<const A> a = std::make_shared<const B>();
// or
const std::shared_ptr<const A> a = std::make_shared<const B>();
```

, then `dynamic_pointer_cast<B>` wouldn't work, but `dynamic_pointer_cast<const B>` would work.